# In Web3, why is simply signing transactions with private key more secure than unlocking the account and using sendTransaction?

Tags: web3js, wallets, sendtransaction, sendsignedtransaction

In [Can anybody Point out the Difference between Web3.eth.sendTransaction and web3.eth.signTransaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73683/can-anybody-point-out-the-difference-between-web3-eth-sendtransaction-and-web3-e), the author of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73705/61096 mentions how unlocking an account in code is not a good idea and proceeds to sign a transaction using the private key directly. But why is using the private key better than unlocking the account?

Comment: Because if somebody hacks the node which maintains your unlocked account, then they can exploit your account at will.

Comment: BTW, the author of that question does not mention such thing!

Comment: My bad. I meant your answer on that question.
However, wouldn't hacking our node with this application code (the one that unlocks using private key) also allow them to exploit the account at will?

Comment: You don't have to keep your private key in the application code. You can, for example, encrypt it with a password, which the owner of the private key will enter each time he or she wants to perform the transaction (a luxury which you lack when keeping your account unlocked on the remote node).

Comment: I'm not an expert in security though, so you might wanna consult on that in the appropriate forum.

Comment: I was simply curious how the manual signing with private key could be better. So it's cool