# what is difference between web3.eth.sendTransaction and web3.eth.personal.sendTransaction on Web3.js

Tags: web3js

I checked there is difference between `sendTransaction` and `sendSignedTransaction`. ([Can anybody Point out the Difference between Web3.eth.sendTransaction and web3.eth.signTransaction?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73683/can-anybody-point-out-the-difference-between-web3-eth-sendtransaction-and-web3-e/73705#73705))

but I found there are two `sendTransaction` methods on `web3.js (v1.7.4)`.

First one is `web3.eth.sendTransaction`. (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction)

The other one is `web3.eth.personal.sendTransaction`. (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.4/web3-eth-personal.html#sendtransaction)

It seems the latter one has security issue though (use with `web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount`), What is use of first one?

I thought The general way of sending transaction on `web3.js` is below.

1.`web3.eth.signTransaction`
2.`web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`

then, What is use of `web3.eth.sendTransaction`?

Answer (score 1):

This is answer from @nikoulai on *web3.js* github repository issue. (https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/5191#issuecomment-1172155634)

here are two different questions.

First, regarding personal sendTransaction. Taken from the documentation:

The `web3-eth-personal` package allows you to interact with the Ethereum node’s accounts. So using this sendTransaction you are trying to execute the transaction using one of the accounts in the node.

Regarding the second part, `web3.eth.signTransaction` & `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` vs `web3.eth.sendTransaction`. Internally, `sendTransaction` signs the transaction and maybe is the most used. Signing and sending the transaction if different steps is more flexible. You can use an account to sign the transaction and another to send and pay for the fees etc.